# Is it possible to extract number of output bytes and processed bytes from view which was used within query basing on data access logs?

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to find cost/billed bytes of views used within some queries.
**Main goal of this is to find how much money I would save if views were tables.**

As a algorithm I want to find  queries using views (already done) and then run these queries firstly in original form and then with table which would be created by script/me basing on query used within view.
When I was looking into `jobInsertRequest.resource.jobStatistics` to find all matching queries I found there is eg field `totalViewsProcessed` or `totalLoadOutputBytes`
Does someone know if it is possible to distinguish from above statistics or others processed bytes of views in comparison to output bytes of these views?

Comment: Do you mean, have the breakdown of processed bytes per view in a query?

Comment: yes, but additionally I would like to have for every view sth similar to jobr.jobStatistics.queryOutputRowCount where there is queryOutputBytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rowCount and processedBytes information for the referenced views is not currently available in the audit logs nor in the [JobStatistics](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobstatistics2). In the [QueryStage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#explainquerystage) object from the API there's more information that can help having more insights about the bytesProcessed at different stages; however, it is not a straightforward conversion to what you're looking for, and for most cases it wouldn't even be possible to get the information on a per-view basis.

My suggestion is to create a Feature Request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162685) to ask the BigQuery team to make available the information you're looking for in the audit logs.